# Injected HTML accessing the Chrome API and global variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, html-injections

I'm working on a Chrome Extension, and I'm new to the process. The extension I'm working on injects an HTML sidebar into the page, injects java-script functions to the header, then let's the user press the buttons on the sidebar to create/save my extension's data.

However, when I want to save the information, I use localStorage, however, the localStorage always saves with respect to the current website. How can I use localStorage to save with respect to our extension?

Furthermore, I would like to use some global javascript variables in the chrome-extension. Where do these belong? I know I can't currently access them from the injected Javascript.

I've looked into message passing, and I've had some trouble with it. I'm not sure how it works in the scope of injected javascript into a page's header. I've tried working with this example, but my extension doesn't seem to catch the message.

```
// This function is called in the injected header javascript.
function sendToExtension() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('page javascript sending message');
    window.postMessage({ type: 'page_js_type',
        text: "Hello from the page's javascript!"},
        '*' /* targetOrigin: any */);
    }, 10);
}

// This is installed in a background script.
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log('content_script.js got message:', event);
});
```

Comment: Tip: Use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) instead of `localStorage`. Since postMessage is asynchronous already, you would probably not have any trouble with changing your code.

Comment: Hm, I would look into this more, since it looks like a useful API - but I still have the problem that injected HTML can't access the chrome APIs.

Comment: You've put the right solution in your answer: Use `postMessage` and `onmessage`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Chrome's sendMessage function and onMessage listener. See below:

```
function sendToExtension() {
    console.log('Sending message');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ext: "myExtension"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.ack);
    });
}

// Listener - Put this in the background script to listen to all the events.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.ext) {
        console.log('Message received from ' + request.ext);
        sendResponse({ack:'received'}); // This send a response message to the requestor
    }
});
```

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for, but "sendToExtension" is called from an injected HTML script. From there, I can't access the 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage' API.

Comment: What I ended up doing was passing from the window to the content script, and then from the content script to the background script.